# How to zoom into x axis for multiple Flot charts that were created

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to get zoomin to work for the Flot charts created using following code.

```
var options = {
                yaxis: { min: 0 },
                xaxis: { mode: "time" },
                series:{
                         lines: { show: true },
                         points: { show: true }
                       },
                grid: {
                        hoverable: true, 
                        clickable: false, 
                        mouseActiveRadius: 30,
                        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#D1D1D1", "#7A7A7A"] }
                       },
                selection:{mode: "x"}
              };
var pdata = [];
for (var key in datasets) {
        pdata = [];
         pdata.push(datasets[key]);
        $.plot( $('<div style="width:1200px;height:600px;"></div>').appendTo('#placeholder'),pdata,options);
        $('<h5 align="center">'+datasets[key]['label']+'</h5>').appendTo('#placeholder');
        $('<br>').appendTo('#placeholder');
        $("#placeholder").UseTooltip();
    };
```

Here I'm creating multiple charts in a loop.
How can I add zoomin feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flot` generally expects it's place holder div to have a unique `id`.  You would then use this unique `id` to assign a specific `plotselected` event to that plot.  The way you have your code structured, though, you are appending the real placeholder div to a parent div as you create your plots.  I like your approach so we need to work around flot's limitation.

So, in your `plot` call give your real placeholder div a class name.  This will give us something to bind the `plotselected` event to.  Also you need to save a reference to all the plot objects you've created.  I'd just use a global array.

```
myPlots.push(
   $.plot( $('<div class="myPlot" style="width:300px;height:100px;"></div>').appendTo('#placeholder'),pdata,options)
);
```

Where `myPlots` is the global array and my class is `myPlot`.

After this, you can set up the `plotselected` handler on the jquery selector `.myPlots`.  Next for the tricky part, you need to find your plot object reference inside the handler.  The easiest way to do this, I found, is to loop your `myPlots` array and compare their divs to the div the event happens on:

```
$(".myPlot").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myPlots.length; i++)
    {
        var aPlot = myPlots[i];
        if (aPlot.getPlaceholder()[0] == event.currentTarget) //this is the correct plot
        {
            var opts = myPlots[i].getOptions();
            opts.xaxes[0].min = ranges.xaxis.from;
            opts.xaxes[0].max = ranges.xaxis.to; 
            myPlots[i].setupGrid();
            myPlots[i].draw();
        }        
    }    
});
```

You'll see above I'm redrawing the plot a little different than in the flot [examples](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/selection/index.html).  I prefer this method since you don't have to remember the data, you adjust the min/max options and you redraw.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/jr94g/) putting this all together.

Comment: See my answer below for a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to Mark's answer: unique IDs are not really a Flot limitation; that's a requirement of the HTML spec.  Browsers generally let you get away with breaking this rule, but it's still not a good idea.  Mark's answer is good, but here's one that doesn't require an array-search on every event:

```
$.each(datasets, function(key, dataset) {
    var element = $('<div style="width:1200px;height:600px;"></div>')
        .appendTo('#placeholder');
    var plot = $.plot(element, [dataset], options);
    var plotOptions = plot.getOptions();
    element.bind('plotselected', function(event, ranges) {
        plotOptions.xaxes[0].min = ranges.xaxis.from;
        plotOptions.xaxes[0].max = ranges.xaxis.to;
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();
    });
};
```

Comment: I bow to the master :)  When I said limitation it was not so much the unique id per element HTML spec but more that flot does not auto-pass the plot object instance into it's event handler (with highcharts, for instance, the `this` in the handler is always the chart instance).  So if you bind multiple plots to a handler, you need to find the plot object you really want to act on me.  It never dawned on me to do it with a closure as you've done above.

Comment: I agree; plot should be either bound or passed to the callback.